# How to fill HTML form with javascript and then submitting it

Tags: javascript, html, django

I'm trying to build a website with Django. On the website, the user can fill in a list of ingredients by selecting from a library. This part works fine. Trouble starts when I want the list to be submitted. I've written the following form:

```
<ul id="user_ing_list" class="content">
</ul>   
<div class="headline">
    <form action="{% url 'opskriftssoegning:soegeresultat' %}" method="get" accept-charset="utf-8">
        <button type="submit" name="ingsoegning" onclick="prepare_user_ing_list()">Find opskrifter</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

When clicking the button, the following JavaScript function should run:

```
var user_ing_list = document.getElementById("user_ing_list");

function prepare_user_ing_list() {
    var result_list = [];
    for (ing in user_ing_list) {
        result_list.append(ing)
    };
    return result_list;
}
```

I thought the form would receive the list of items from the function and submit it, but the resulting Django view tells me that nothing was submitted. What have I done wrong?

Comment: There is no array.append() method in JavaScript and what is a for in loop over DOM supposed to do? Really unclear what you are expecting to be added to the array. If you want something to be part of a form submission, than you need something to submit that is an input element....

Comment: No, returning a value from a submit button’s `onclick` listener does not make it part of the form (or do anything at all, if it’s not false).

Comment: The html element that allows you to input ingredients needs to be in the form. I would think this would be the natural way to go about doing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I din't know what you want to submit as list, but if you want to 
get content of `li` as list in form, should doing something like this :

1) Change `type="submit"` to `type="button"` that prevent auto submit.

2) You can not using loop over `ul` and should get `li` children's.

3) should append you info into form, and for appending list into form data
can using `hidden` input with `[]` that means data is list.

4) After adding your data to form,can submit form.

Try something like this :

```
<ul id="user_ing_list" class="content">

</ul>

<div class="headline">
    <form action="{% url 'opskriftssoegning:soegeresultat' %}" method="get" accept-charset="utf-8" id="ing_form">
        <button type="button" name="ingsoegning" onclick="prepare_user_ing_list()">Find opskrifter</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

js :

```
    var user_ing_list = document.getElementById("user_ing_list");
    var form          = document.getElementById('ing_form');

    function prepare_user_ing_list() {

        // Find li items inside ul
        var items = user_ing_list.getElementsByTagName("li");

        for (var i = 0; i < items.length; ++i) {

            var input = document.createElement('input');

            input.setAttribute('name', 'list[]');
            input.setAttribute('value', items[i].textContent);
            input.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');

            form.appendChild(input);
        }
        // Submit the form
        form.submit();
    }
```